# Copy-pasting external (Wikipedia) entries into tag excerpts and SO wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

[A user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065190/sergey-k) has been making some Wiki edits while I was reviewing. I noticed that his edits were actually sentences copy-pasted from various sources like project homepages or Wikipedia.

In general, these edits make sense, though I hesitate to accept them.

Comment: Does this user attribute the quote to the source? If not, these should be rejected.

Comment: Yeah - some of those are lifted directly from sites, without linking to them (and text that is links in the original isn't in the suggested edit). This isn't right.

Comment: Funny, my rejection votes got overriden on damn near every one of those edits, and was just about to send a message to the user when I noticed this on Meta.  Glad it's getting some attention.

Comment: @DariusZ Did you mean to break the user link?

Comment: @RichardTingle I did not, corrected it, sorry